# Oracle: numeric or value error

Tags: java, oracle

I am calling a function from my java code and i am getting this exception. I have checked all the data types and everything else I can think of but I am still getting this exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error:
>   character to number conversion error

```
if (rs.next()) {
                String originalOrderNature = rs.getString("ORDER_NATURE");
                String stExCode = rs.getString("ST_EX_CODE");
                long orderNumber = rs.getLong("ORDER_NUMBER");
                String client_code = rs.getString("CLIENT_CODE");
                String st_ex_code = rs.getString("ST_EX_CODE");
                String isin = rs.getString("ISIN");
                String symbol = rs.getString("SYMBOL");
                String market_type = rs.getString("MARKET_TYPE");
                String buy_or_sell = rs.getString("BUY_OR_SELL");
                int volume = rs.getInt("VOLUME");
                float rate_limit = rs.getFloat("RATE_LIMIT");
                String order_nature = rs.getString("ORDER_NATURE");
                Date valid_till = rs.getDate("VALID_TILL");
                String order_status_id = rs.getString("ORDER_STATUS_ID");
                aryMarginParam.add(0, originalOrderNature);
                aryMarginParam.add(1, stExCode);
                aryMarginParam.add(2, orderNumber);
                aryMarginParam.add(3, client_code);
                aryMarginParam.add(4, st_ex_code);
                aryMarginParam.add(5, isin);
                aryMarginParam.add(6, symbol);
                aryMarginParam.add(7, market_type);
                aryMarginParam.add(8, buy_or_sell);
                aryMarginParam.add(9, volume);
                aryMarginParam.add(10, rate_limit);
                aryMarginParam.add(11, order_nature);
                aryMarginParam.add(12, valid_till);
                aryMarginParam.add(13, order_status_id);
            }
```

In this function i am passing this arrayList

```
String statement = "BEGIN ? := abc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?); END;";

    Object[] in = new Object[13];
    int[] out = new int[2];
    String OriginalOrderNature = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(0);
    String stExCode = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(1);
    long orderNumber = (Long) arrVerifyMargin.get(2);
    String client_code = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(3);
    String st_ex_code = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(4);
    String isin = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(5);
    String symbol = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(6);
    String market_type = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(7);
    String buy_or_sell = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(8);
    int volume = (Integer) arrVerifyMargin.get(9);
    float rate_limit = (Float) arrVerifyMargin.get(10);
    String order_nature = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(11);
    Date valid_till = (Date) arrVerifyMargin.get(12);
    String order_status_id = (String) arrVerifyMargin.get(13);
    int modifyy = modify;   
    //float float_volume = (float)volume;
    System.out.println(OriginalOrderNature + " " + stExCode);

    out[0] = Types.VARCHAR;
    in[0] = orderNumber;
    in[1] = client_code;
    in[2] = st_ex_code;
    in[3] = isin;
    in[4] = symbol;
    in[5] = market_type;
    in[6] = buy_or_sell;
    in[7] = volume;
    in[8] = rate_limit;
    in[9] = order_nature;
    in[10] = valid_till;
    in[11] = order_status_id;
    in[12] = modifyy;
    out[1] = Types.VARCHAR;
    String orderNature = (DAOHelper.call(statement, in, out))[1].toString();
    return orderNature;
```

Comment: I'm sure you did check everything, as you claim, however, it's clear that you've overlooked something.  There's nothing anyone can do to help you unless you edit your question and add more details.  Specifically, show us the code.  If you can't show us the code, there's not much to say, other than "stop making character to number conversion errors".

Comment: Provided information is not enough to get what's wrong

Comment: You should have to include **code** with this question.

Comment: It seems like conversation error.

Comment: you should provide some code to let others know what is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you clearly what the problem is.  For some reasons the PL/SQL is trying to convert character data to a number, and it can't.

You need to believe the error message, and try and figure out *why* the problem is happening; e.g. what those characters are and why they won't convert.

I'm not a PL/SQL expert, but you need to consider things such as:

- non-numeric characters in the string being converted,
- leading or trailing whitespace,
- embedded ','s or the like entered by a user,
- a spurious decimal point if the target type is an integer
- multiple decimal points, etc if the target type is a floating point type
- too many input digits for the size of the target type

Some of these could result in different errors, but it is definitely the case that more than one of the above *could* result in that error message.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
String statement = "BEGIN ? := abc(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?); END;";
```

You cannot use a placeholder (?) after the `BEGIN`.